# How to create a 2D array and calculate the average of it?

Tags: c++, arrays, 2d, average

THE PROBLEM

Create a 4X3 integer array and fill it, column by column, with the odd numbers starting with 1.  In a separate, one dimensional array, store the average of each column of the 4X3 array.  Output the 4X3 array (as a 4X3 array) and output the average of each column underneath each column.  Label these as the average.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    // variables defined here
    int i, j, A[4][3], average[3], sum = 0, oddnumber = 1;

    for(i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for(j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            A[j][i] = oddnumber;
            oddnumber = oddnumber + 2;
            sum = sum + A[j][i];
        }

        average[i] = sum / 4.0;

        sum = 0;
    }

    // output
    cout << "The Array is: \n";

    for(i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for(j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            cout << A[i][j] << "\n";
        }
    }

    cout << "Average: \n";

    for(i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        cout << average[i] << "\n";
    }
}
```

When I run the program, the values does not appear in a table (2D array) but in one column only.

Comment: What issue do you get with this code?

Comment: @Damien when i run the program, the values are not appeared in a table (2D array) but one column

Comment: You don't print the `\n` at the right place. Do it at the end of each line only.

Comment: That's because you asked it to. Rethink where you `<< "\n";`

Comment: Thank you so much guys

Answer (score 0):

You get one column only because you output a newline (`\n`) after each number.

```
for(i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    for(j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        cout << A[i][j] << "\n";  // here
    }
}
```

Instead, output the newline *after* each row has been printed. You may also want to insert a tab (`\t`) or space between the numbers in each row to not get a very long number as output:

```
for(i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    for(j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        std::cout << A[i][j] << '\t'; // a tab after each number in the row
    }
    std::cout << '\n';  // newline after the row is done
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It really helped me

Comment: @LedinaBanushllari Great, you're welcome!